# Convert the hex string to readable output

Tags: python, string, hex

I receive the value "\E8\x03" from another program into my python program and it is actually the value "1000" i.e 0x3E8. How do I make this conversion from that input string?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you missing an `x` in that string?

Comment: The string is really `"\xe8\x03"`, isn't it?

Comment: I thought so, is there a way to replace the "\" with an "\x"

Comment: it should be that, but it isnt. so I am trying to get it to that

Comment: Wow, seriously? The author of that program should be slapped with a wet fish. Like, how does that even happen?

Comment: ill do that in class tomorrow :D

Comment: eh, I'm not sure this output makes enough sense. deleted my answer, but interested to see what comes of this.

Comment: So the second half of that string is not a `\x03` character, it's a literal backslash followed by "x03"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's clean up the string:

```
>>> clean_hex = re.sub(r'\\x?([a-f0-9]{2})', lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1), 16)), r"\E8\x03", flags=re.I)
>>> clean_hex
'\xe8\x03'
```

And then we can use the struct module:

```
>>> struct.unpack('<H', clean_hex)[0]
1000
```

Comment: NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: @SoumilDeshpande `import re` for the regex module.